# Converting BSON file to JSON results in missing content

Tags: python, json, bson

I'm trying to convert a .bson file to .json. I've tried using bson to json websites, both of them return the same thing as the python code.

```
bson_file = open('fishes.bson', 'rb')
b = bson.loads(bson_file.read())
print(b)
```

this returns:

```
{'_id': b'5ac88a55eadcdf42044615bb', 'imgurl': 'http://www.fishbase.org/images/thumbnails/jpg/tn_Prweb_u0.jpg', 'rarity': 1, 'id': 0, 'length': 3.1, 'name': 'Aapticheilichthys websteri', 'fishLength': 3.1}
```

the bson file is 2.68 MB so i dont think it should ONLY have that. Is the bson file invalid? How else can i access the bson file? 
I am using python 3.8.1.

[Fishes.bson](http://www.mediafire.com/file/oec0cg3xtbqwqw8/fishes.bson/file) and
[virustotal of the bson](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/f35c4fea3f410be66518406ca089f7fd07077a77dbedbcb6090232acc33d2824/detection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the bson library *does* contain my answer.

```
bson.decode_all(bson_file)
```

This didnt work **for me**, because apparently my environment is janked. But someone else helped me out, and ran the code, which worked. Now i have to figure out whats wrong with my environment...